# Why does Rust need the PartialOrd trait in addition to the Ord trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I want to define `Ord` for a custom type `Point` so it is sorted by the distance to the origin for [Advent of Code 2019 day 10](https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/10):

```
impl std::cmp::Ord for Point {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> std::cmp::Ordering {
        let this = self.x * self.x + self.y + self.y;
        let that = other.x * other.x + other.y * other.y;
        return this.cmp(&that);
    }
}
```

However, I ran into this compile error:

> = help: the trait `std::cmp::PartialOrd` is not implemented for `helpers::models::Point`

The documentation for [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html) only explains how to [derive](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html#derivable) it or [implement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html#how-can-i-implement-partialord) it. Those are pretty clear.

Why does `Ord` depend on this? What does the name `Partial` imply in the trait name? When will it get used?

Comment: The difference is described in the first sentence of both pages of documentation: *[PartialOrd is] for values that can be compared for a sort-order.*; *[Ord is] for types that form a total order.*

Comment: Ok @Shepmaster your answer on the other question explains it well. I didn't know the concept of total order and partial order before. TIL. Thanks!