# Why is `PartialOrd` not blanket-implemented for all types that implement `Ord`?

Tags: rust

In the [documentation for `Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html), it says

> Implementations must be consistent with the PartialOrd implementation [...]

That of course makes sense and can easily be archived as in the example further down:

```rust
impl PartialOrd for MyType {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}
```

I wonder, why they would leave this burden / risk to us users instead of having a blanket `impl<T: Ord> PartialOrd for T { /* ... */ }`.

I tested for problems with circular dependencies and stuff [in a playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e397e371aa79eda96b259470d4af1bc5), but that worked as I would expect it. The internet didn't yield any results either.

Another reason I can think of is how the `derive` macros work right now. One would probably have to replace every `derive(PartialOrd, Ord)` with just `derive(Ord)` (or make the macro for `PartialOrd` smarter - I don't know if it can become that smart though).

Adding the suggested blanket impl would forbid custom implementations of `PartialOrd` and eliminate the requirement for consistency. Of course, that would now be a breaking change in the library. Is that the only reason, or am I missing some other arguments here?

Comment: A starting point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59315296/why-does-rust-need-the-partialord-trait-in-addition-to-the-ord-trait

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It *would* be a good idea to have a blanket implementation of `Ord` for types that implement `PartialOrd`. The reason that such a blanket implementation doesn't exist is because it's not technically possible. Just adding a `impl<T: Ord> PartialOrd for T` block to `core` would result in an error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::cmp::PartialOrd<&_>` for type `&_`
 --> src/lib.rs:1:1
  |
1 | impl<T: Ord> PartialOrd for T {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
          - impl<A, B> PartialOrd<&B> for &A
            where A: PartialOrd<B>, A: ?Sized, B: ?Sized;
```

There is already a blanket implementation in `core` that implements `PartialOrd` for all references to `PartialOrd` types. By implementing `PartialOrd` for *all* types that implement `Ord`, it would be possible to have `PartialOrd` implemented for the same type twice. It would then be unclear which implementation should be used. Consider this code:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
struct X;
impl PartialOrd for X {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        panic!("1");
    }
}
impl Ord for &X {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        panic!("2");
    }
}
```

Here are the traits that get implemented on `X`

- `X: PartialOrd` (directly implemented), panics with `1`
- `&X: PartialOrd` (blanket implementation for references), panics with `1`
- `&X: Ord` (directly implemented), panics with `2`

But if we were to implement `PartialOrd` automatically, then there would be an additional implementation of `PartialOrd` on `&X` that panics with `2`. It is ambiguous how it should be resolved.

The solution to this is to use specialization, which is an unstable feature in Rust, that didn't even exist when Rust 1.0 was released. As such, not implementing `PartialOrd` was the only option. Specialization allows the same item to have multiple conflicting trait implementations in a way that is unambiguous, but it is currently unstable, unsound, and nightly only. See [this Rust issue for more details on the issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63104).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is a reference to that, in a github issue - [rust-lang/rust#63104](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63104#issuecomment-515960346):

> This conflicts with the existing blanket impl in core.
>
> ```rust
> error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::cmp::PartialOrd<&_>` > for type `&_`:
>  --> src/lib.rs:3:1
>   |
> 3 | impl<T: Ord> PartialOrd for T {
>   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   |
>   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
>           - impl<A, B> std::cmp::PartialOrd<&B> for &A
>             where A: std::cmp::PartialOrd<B>, A: ?Sized, B: ?Sized;
> ```